# Post or Set MutableLiveData - Observer onChanged not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, rx-android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I discover the new android architecture component and I want to test the couple ViewModel / LiveData through a small test application. The latter has two fragments (in a `ViewPager`), the first creates/updates a list of cards (via an `EditText`) and the second displays all the cards.

**My ViewModel:**

```
public class CardsScanListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData> cardsLiveData = new MutableLiveData();
    private HashMap cardsMap = new HashMap();

    public CardsScanListViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public MutableLiveData> getCardsLiveData() {
        return this.cardsLiveData;
    }

    public void saveOrUpdateCard(String id) {
        if(!cardsMap.containsKey(id)) {
            cardsMap.put(id, new Card(id, new AtomicInteger(0)));
        }
        cardsMap.get(id).getCount().incrementAndGet();
        this.cardsLiveData.postValue(cardsMap);
    }
}
```

**My second fragment:**

```
public class CardsListFragment extends Fragment {

    CardsAdapter cardsAdapter;

    RecyclerView recyclerCardsList;

    public CardsListFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final CardsScanListViewModel viewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CardsScanListViewModel.class);

        observeViewModel(viewModel);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cards_list, container, false);
        recyclerCardsList = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerCardsList);
        recyclerCardsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        cardsAdapter = new CardsAdapter(getActivity());
        recyclerCardsList.setAdapter(cardsAdapter);

        return v;
    }

    private void observeViewModel(CardsScanListViewModel viewModel) {
        viewModel.getCardsLiveData().observe(this, new Observer  > () {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable HashMap  cards) {
                if (cards != null) {
                    cardsAdapter.setCardsList(cards.values());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The`HashMap`, like my `MutableLiveData`, update well but my second fragment doesn't receive the information via observer.

Comment: For information, a simple MutableLiveData <String> (set & get) works in the first fragment of my ViewPager. I tried to reverse the 2 fragments but still the same problem. I changed the HashMap for a List <Card> but still no update. I did the test also with the HasObserver and it is wrong (no observer).

Comment: I have added the solution few days ago using single instance of ViewModel. Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are **observing** the **new instance** of `ViewModel` instead of observing the same `ViewModel` used by your **First** Fragment.

```
final CardsScanListViewModel viewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CardsScanListViewModel.class);
```

Above code initialize new instance of `CardsScanListViewModel` for your second fragment `CardsListFragment`, because you passed `this` as context.
If you update any data from this fragment it will **update** in this **instance** of `ViewModel`.

It works in your first Fragment because it updates data and observes data from same instance of `ViewModel`

To keep data common among ViewModels initiate view model by passing **activity context** instead of fragment context in both the fragments.

```
final CardsScanListViewModel viewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(CardsScanListViewModel.class);
```

This will create **single instance** of `CardsScanListViewModel` and data will be shared between fragments as they are observing `LiveData` from **single instance** of `ViewModel`.

For confirmation, you need to add notifyDataSetChanged() after updating the list if you haven't done that in adapter itself

```
private void observeViewModel(CardsScanListViewModel viewModel) {
    viewModel.getCardsLiveData().observe(this, new Observer  > () {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable HashMap  cards) {
            if (cards != null) {
                cardsAdapter.setCardsList(cards.values());
                cardsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @adityakamble49, thx for your answer. Yes it's that, the Context must be the same between all ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()) for good communication with ViewModel. I've a first fragment who update this latter with 'this' for context. I changed it for getActivity(). Thx again.